# Add new series to category highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to add a series in last category of chart with a value after the chart is drawn  .E.g. in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

I want to add a series in dec with a name say "new series" and some value say "50" .I want to do it with in some function which will be called after the chart is draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/chart-addseries/)

```
and apply this in your high-chart i am giving just an idea by this you can resolve your problem
```

Comment: Basic column chart are different